# How to make an arrow between arrows that is not sloped?

Tags: tikz-cd

I am trying to make a diagram with arrows between arrows.

Here is how it currently looks:

[image]

with code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
& a \arrow[ld, "Rei"', no head, ""{name=r1}] \arrow[rd, "Rei", no head, ""{name=r2}] &                                \\
b \arrow["Neu"', no head, loop, distance=2em, in=305, out=235] &
& c \arrow[d, "PosRes", no head] \\
&                                                           & d
& \arrow[no head, from=r1, to=r2, dashed]
\end{tikzcd}
```

I would like that dashed line to be straight. It appears to me that this happens because the arrow is "pointing" to the label of the right-most "Rei" arrow. I would like it to point to the center of it, so that the line is straight. However, I cannot find how to do this. Is there a general way to specify that the "arrow between arrows" should point to the center of each arrow (rather than the labels)? If not, what would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: You might like https://q.uiver.app/, a very nice (free, online) commutative diagram editor that has that feature and can export tikz code

Comment: @Nathaniel that is splendid, thank you so much! I used another tool to create this which did not support arrows between arrows. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could specify the `to` coordinate as the point on the same height as `r1`, but below `r2`. Additionally you can use `shorten >` (and `shorten <`, if needed) to adjust the length. Something like `to=r1-|r2, shorten >=0.5em`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& a \arrow[ld, "Rei"', no head, ""{name=r1}] \arrow[rd, "Rei", no head, ""{name=r2}] &                                \\
b \arrow["Neu"', no head, loop, distance=2em, in=305, out=235] &
& c \arrow[d, "PosRes", no head] \\
&                                                           & d
& \arrow[no head, from=r1, to=r1-|r2, dashed,shorten >=0.5em]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Almost the same as @gernot answer (+1, he beat me for a minute, but my code is wee bit shorter):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[arrows=-]
    & a \arrow[ld, "\mathrm{Rei}"', ""{name=r1}] 
        \arrow[rd, "\mathrm{Rei}" , ""{name=r2}] 
        &                                \\
b \arrow["\mathrm{Neu}"', loop, distance=2em, in=305, out=235] 
    &
        & c \arrow[d, "\mathrm{PosRes}"] \\
    &   & d
        & \arrow[from=r1, to=r2 |-r1, dashed, shorten >=0.5em]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 to everybody...but is it possible to use xy package? No I think. :-) You are very closer to 200k :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much. I'm not familiar with `xy`, so regarding it I don't know. Yeh, 200 k is close ;-)

Answer (score 4):

My code it is off-topic with the tag, but also the forgotten [xy](/questions/tagged/xy) package can do the same code like `tikz-cd`. Here there is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=4pc{\ar @{} [dr] |{\hspace{2.1cm} -------}
& a \ar@{-}[dl]_{\mathrm{Rei}} \ar@{-}[dr]^{\mathrm{Rei}}& \\
b \ar@{-}@(dl,dr)_{\mathrm{Neu}}& & c \ar@{-}[d]^{\mathrm{Pos\,Res}}\\
 &  & d
}
\end{document}
```

The line are right...if you make a zoom you get the straight lines.

[image]